# Calculating Overtake Time for Two Cars

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving

Yes I've seen several similar questions but they all seem to not have the same provided information as what I'm looking for. Given my very rusty math skills I've been unable to convert the answers I've found there to my use.

Car A is traveling at 20mph. Car B is traveling at 40mph and is 1 mile behind car A. How long will it take for Car B to overtake Car A?

I'm really looking for the correct formula here. So I could reword this to look more like:

Car A is traveling at *a* mph. Car B is traveling at *b* mph and is *d* miles behind car A. How much time (*t*) in hours will it take Car B to overtake Car A?

Thanks ahead of time. I've been trying to turn this into a formula and have been humbled by my inability to wrap my ahead around what seems to me to be a simple question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Start by snowing B is approaching A at b - a mph.

Comment: So we'd have a relative velocity of _b_ - _a_. And _d_ is a relative distance. But it's not as simple as just solving for time: d/(b-a) is it?

Comment: It is that simple